# Fragment Shader inconsistancy

Tags: fragment-shader

I have added fog to my fragment shader, which works really well on specific devices. However on my Samsung's I just get pure grey. Would anyone know why?

relevant part of shader:

```
        + "     vec4 fog_color = vec4(0.47, 0.549, 0.552, 0.0);\n"                      
        + "     float dist = (gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w);\n"
        + "     float fogFactor = (nearFog - dist)/(nearFog - farFog);\n"
        + "     fogFactor = clamp( 1.0-fogFactor, 0.0, 1.0 );\n"
        + "     gl_FragColor = mix(fog_color, gl_FragColor, fogFactor);\n"
```

Comment: After some investigation I'm finding that if I double my nearFog and farFog values it works. But I need help understanding why that is the case and how I get the scaling value from each device?

Comment: What values are you using for nearFog and farFog (the original broken values, before you doubled them)?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question, this was to do with some anti-aliasing settings I was using.